# Проблема с задачей на поиск в массиве/arraylist

Tags: java

Есть задача - Напечатать фамилию, имя, отчество и адрес сотрудников...(Златопольский 13.12)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class workexp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database DB = new Database();
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(new Employee("Путин", "Владимир", "Владимирович", 2000, 12));
        employees.add(new Employee("Медведев", "Дмитрий", "Анатольевич", 2008, 5));
        employees.add(new Employee("Хренова", "Гадя", "Петрович", 2017, 3));
        employees.add(new Employee("Кшыштопоповжецкая", "Изольда", 2017, 5));
    }
}


class Employee {
    String surname;
    String name;
    String patronymic;
    int year;
    int month;

    public Employee(String surname, String name, int year, int month) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronymic = "";
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
    }

    public Employee(String surname, String name, String patronymic, int year, int month) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronymic = patronymic;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth() {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return surname + name + patronymic;
    }


    int getWorkinExpirienceOnDate() {
        if (LocalDate.now().getYear() - year > 3) {
            return System.out.println(Employee.getFullName());
        } else if (LocalDate.now().getYear() - year == 3) {
            if (((LocalDate.now().getMonth()) - month) >= 0) {
                return Employee.getFullName();
            }
        } else break;
        break;
    }

}

class Database(Employee[]employees) {
Employee[] findEmployees(String FullNameSubstring) {
// if Employee == getFullName return Employee.experience //видимо возврат опыта работы по фамилии
}

Employee[] findEmployees(int workingYears) {
//if Employee == experience return employee.getfullname  //видимо возврат фамилии по опыту работу
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень правильный вопрос, думаю ответ будет вам очень полезен.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class MoreThanthree {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        ArrayList<Employee> staff = new ArrayList<>();
        staff.add(new Employee("Путин", "Владимир", "Владимирович", "Ново-Огарёво", LocalDate.of(2000, 12, 1)));
        staff.add(new Employee("Медведев", "Дмитрий", "Анатольевич", "рядом с Путиным, иначе всесте с Шпаком", LocalDate.of(2008, 5, 1)));
        staff.add(new Employee("Семён", "Семёнович", "Шпак", "Мухосранск", LocalDate.of(2008, 8, 1)));
        staff.add(new Employee("Антон", "Городецкий", "Батькович", "рядом с Мухосранском", LocalDate.of(2010, 1, 1)));
        staff.add(new Employee("Гадя", "Петрович", "Хренова", "Москва", LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 1)));
        staff.add(new Employee("Оксана", "Оксановна", "Петрович", "деревня Гадюкино", LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 1)));

        System.out.println("СПИСОК ВСЕХ РАБОТНИКОВ");
        staff.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("*************************************************");

        final int experienceInYear = 3;
        System.out.println("СПИСОК РАБОТНИКОВ, СО СТАЖЕМ РАБОТЫ ОТ "+experienceInYear+" ЛЕТ");        

        staff.stream()
                .filter(employee->employee.experienceInYear()>=experienceInYear)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}

class Employee {

    private final String surname;
    private final String name;
    private final String patronomic;
    private final String city;
    private final LocalDate experience;

    public Employee(String surname, String name, String patronomic, 
            String city, LocalDate experience){
        this.surname = surname;
        this.name = name;
        this.patronomic = patronomic;
        this.city = city;
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public int experienceInYear () {
        return Period.between(experience, LocalDate.now()).getYears();        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return surname + " " + name + " " + patronomic + ", стаж в годах : " + experienceInYear ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, почему public String toString() нигде не выполняется, но без нее не работает?
И еще if ((LocalDate.now()-LocalDate.of(______))>3) как правильно написать в скобках после .of ?
Т.е. я не понимаю как ВЫНУТЬ из person this.experience

Comment: @Eugene процитайте про метода object и переопределение методов. на самом деле этот метод вызывается у объекта, когда вы передаете объект в System.out.println

Comment: @Eugene вам не надо писать  if ((LocalDate.now()-LocalDate.of(______))>3). для этого у вас есть метод experienceInYear (). вы вызываете его у объекта, у которго хотите посчитать опыт. метод  сравнивает текущую дату и дату, которую передали при создании объекта - начала трудового стажа, возвращает вам опыт в годах. выглядит это примерно так if (person.experienceInYear()>3).

Comment: Дмитрий, подскажите почему у меня неправильное применение методов к объектам Employee. Код добавлен в конце вопроса. И как реализовать окончание метода. IDE жалуется на break/continue/пустой return.

Comment: простите, а что вы делаете? вы пытаетесь найти работников со стажем более 3 лет? а заодно почитайте хотя бы про GRASP, в 10 строчках кода нарушены все принципы и паттерны, которые только существуют. если хотите и непонятно что такое грасп, могу поделиться ссылкой с корпаративной лекции, где я про грасп рассказываю. и этот добавленный код... это метод какого класса?

Comment: Тот который я к вам добавил, его надо удалить. Я не туда добавил. Я хотел в свой добавить.
Вообще это метод класса Person(у меня сейчас Employee).

Comment: хорошо, а цель кода какая?

Comment: я изменил ответ, пересмотрите еще раз

Comment: Я не сомневаюсь, что ваш код работает. Просто мне надо чтобы мой тоже работал. Вы говорите, GRASP нарушен. Я вот и спрашиваю, где?
Вроде бы есть класс person(у меня Employee). Я к нему применяю его же методы. И вот тут уже неправильно. Я не понимаю почему.

Comment: для начала все таки нужно понять, какая цель этого метода? что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Как уже было сказано, я пытаюсь среди имеющихся данных, найти удовлетворяющие критерию. Работник>3 года стажа.

Comment: загрузите мой код и сравните свой с моим. ваш код вообще не компилируется, там почему-то стринг возвращается вместо задекларированного инта и брейк без цикла. синтаксис языка нарушен, здесь не идер речь о некорректной работе, все ломается еще на компиляции. если есть вопросы как работает мой код и почему так, то задавайте и я объясню

Comment: Можно еще вопросик. Вы делаете employee.experienceInYear(). У вас правильно. Я делаю Employee.getFullName(). У меня неправильно. Что у меня не так ?

Comment: дело не в том, что вы пытаетесь создать метод. дело в том, как вы это используете. назначение этого метода-создать строку, которая в дальнейшем будем выведена в консоль. для этого у класса object уже существует метод toString.после чего вы пытаетесь вызывать его (метод) из метода, который считает стаж. так делать нельзя.метод должен иметь единое назначение. если он считает стаж, то пусть возвращает стаж,к примеру, в годах. таким образом, у объекта будет набор методов, каждый из которых будет иметь четкое предназначение. иначе у вас будет путаница в невозможность переиспользования методов

Comment: Но вы ведь нигде не используете toString() ?
Есть определение метода в классе, и всё.

Comment: я уже отвечал на этот вопрос и говорил прочитать про методы object. метод toString я  использую здесь - forEach(System.out::println). суть в том, что если взять перемнную, которая хранит в себе объект, и передать ее в данном случае в System.out::println, то этот метод вызовет у данной переменной метод toString.это происходит потому, что для вывода в консоль нужно строчное представление объекта (преобразовать его в стринг), а вот каким образом это делать и определено в методе toString

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107169/discussion-between-eugene-and-).